# Displaying JFreeChart in a web page using Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2, jfreechart

I am using Struts2. I need to display JFreeChart in a web page. Can any body help me on that?

Edit: it is getting displayed in binary format.

```
public String execute() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Refresh bar Chart");
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    OutputStream outstream = response.getOutputStream();
    try {
        JFreeChart chart = getChartViewer();
        ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(outstream, chart, 500, 300);
        System.out.println("Created bar Chart");
        return SUCCESS;
    } finally {
        outstream.close();
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've reformatted the code from your comment; revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your charts to images and include them in your HTML files.

Comment: public String execute() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Refresh bar Chart");
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        OutputStream outstream = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            JFreeChart chart = getChartViewer();
            ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(outstream,chart,500,300);

            System.out.println("Created bar Chart");
            return SUCCESS;
        } finally {

            outstream.close();
            response.flushBuffer();
        }

            
 
    }
it is getting displayed in binary formate

Answer (score 1):

JSP/Struts2/whatever-MVC pages always ends up as HTML. To display images in HTML, you need the `<img>` element or whatever MVC component you'd normally to use to render a HTML `<img>` element. To locate an image, you need to let its `src` attribute point to a valid URL which returns the image. This can be a static or dynamic resource, the client doesn't see the difference.

```
<img src="images/foo.png">
```

In a JSP/Servlet environment, the normal practice is to let a Servlet listen on the particular URL using `url-pattern` in `web.xml` such as `/images/*` and let it create/load/find the image based on request parameters or pathinfo and write the image to the outputstream of the response along a correct set of response headers.

You can find a basic example [here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin:
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jfreechart-plugin.html